# Use Pivot Table to display number of added and removed "inventory"

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have a set of information stored in an external database, similar to the following format:

Table 1

```
Date, InventoryID, InventoryValue
1-12-2011, 1111-111A, 60
2-12-2011, 1111-111B, 50
3-12-2011, 1111-111C, 30

1-1-2012, 1111-111B, 40
2-1-2012, 1111-111C, 40
3-1-2012, 1111-111D, 40
```

And I need to represent the above results in the following format in Pivot Table:

Table 2

```
Month, Beg Inventory, Added, Removed, Ending Inventory
Jan, 3, 1, 1, 3
```

From Table 1, we can see that 1 item has been added from the Dec'11 inventory into the Jan'12 inventory (1111-111D), and one item removed (1111-111A), resulting in the results in Table 2.

When I double click on the "Added" or "Removed" inventory, I should be able to view which InventoryID they belong to. The table should also reflect the "Added" and "Removed" for the past 12 months.

I'm open to any suggestions to use VBA, or SQL to get my result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution (pure SQL):

```
SELECT right(convert(varchar, tbl.[Date], 106), 8) [Date],
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Table1] t1 WHERE month(t1.[Date]) = (tbl.m - 1) AND year(t1.[Date])=tbl.y) [Begin],
(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Table1 t1
    WHERE month(t1.[Date]) = tbl.m
    AND year(t1.[Date])=tbl.y
    AND t1.InventoryID NOT IN (
        SELECT InventoryID
        FROM Table1
        WHERE month(t1.[Date]) = month(DATEADD(month, 1, [Date])) AND year(t1.[Date]) = year([Date]))) [Added],
(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Table1 t1
    WHERE month(t1.[Date]) = (tbl.m - 1)
    AND year(t1.[Date])=tbl.y
    AND t1.InventoryID NOT IN (
        SELECT InventoryID
        FROM Table1
        WHERE month([Date]) = month(DATEADD(month, 1, t1.[Date])) AND year(t1.[Date]) = year([Date]))) [Removed],
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Table1] t1 WHERE month(t1.[Date]) = (tbl.m) AND year(t1.[Date])=tbl.y) [End]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Date], month([Date]) [m], year([Date]) [y] from Table1) as tbl
```

---

### Reproduction:

Sample data script:

```
SELECT * INTO Table1 FROM (
    SELECT GETDATE() [Date], '1111-111A' [InventoryID], 60 [InventoryValue] UNION
    SELECT GETDATE() [Date], '1111-111B' [InventoryID], 50 [InventoryValue] UNION
    SELECT GETDATE() [Date], '1111-111C' [InventoryID], 30 [InventoryValue] UNION

    SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, GETDATE()) [Date], '1111-111B' [InventoryID], 40 [InventoryValue] UNION
    SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, GETDATE()) [Date], '1111-111C' [InventoryID], 40 [InventoryValue] UNION
    SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, GETDATE()) [Date], '1111-111D' [InventoryID], 40 [InventoryValue] UNION

    SELECT DATEADD(month, 2, GETDATE()) [Date], '1111-111B' [InventoryID], 40 [InventoryValue] UNION
    SELECT DATEADD(month, 2, GETDATE()) [Date], '1111-111C' [InventoryID], 40 [InventoryValue] UNION
    SELECT DATEADD(month, 2, GETDATE()) [Date], '1111-111D' [InventoryID], 40 [InventoryValue] UNION
    SELECT DATEADD(month, 2, GETDATE()) [Date], '1111-111F' [InventoryID], 40 [InventoryValue]) as tbl
```

Output:

```
Date        Begin   Added   Removed End
---------------------------------------
Feb 2012    0       3       0       3
Mar 2012    3       1       1       3
Apr 2012    3       1       0       4
```